# Create a simple Java Class in IntelliJ 13

Tags: intellij-idea

When I am using Eclipse I just configure a project in seconds and create classes in seconds. In intelliJ however, I have to be looking all over the place on how ro create a simple Java class. I swear it is not in the new drop down list. Its giving me options for html and leaves out the class for a Java project! Anything would be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just right click on the package you want to create a Java Class in, then select New->Java Class

[image]

You need to make sure you have your source tree marked as a sources root (IntelliJ usually does a good job detecting this on its own for existing sources). If not you will need to mark it as a sources root before you are able to create a Java class. Right click on the sources root then Mark Directory As->Sources Root

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of project you're doing. For example, if you're in a maven project, creating a file should be done in src/main/java. If you right click on this folder, you'll have the possibility to create a java class.

In general, the context menu depends on the context you're calling it.

Hope it helps